# Search REST API call not working for anonymous

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, rest, search-api

I'm trying to execute the following  query for anonymous users. But, its not getting any results. When login, its working fine. Any idea about this ?

`/_api/search/query?QueryText='Category: "About School"'&QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl='spfile://webroot/queryparametertemplate.xml'`

PS: I have added the QueryText and QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl in the queryparametertemplate.xml file.

Comment: Any idea for this issue ?

Comment: Where can I find the queryparametertemplate.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to check in the queryparametertemplate.xml file are whether Farm ID, Site ID & Web ID are configured correctly

1. Farm ID: is the GUID of the farm.
2. Site ID: is the GUID of the site collection where you are you are trying to retrieve your data from.
3. Web ID: The GUID of the root web of the site collection.

You can check this [Sample file](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/go/d-queryparametertemplate/) to verify your settings.

Apart from above checkpoints, you need to enable anonymous access on the catalog you are publishing. That you can do in the Catalog settings page of the list.